# How to Retrieve fields from linked Models

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I have the following three database tables:

```
Products
########
id
title
artist_id

Arists
######
id
profile
person_id

People
######
id
first_name
last_name
```

In my `Product` model how do I create a method to return the product `title` along with the artist's `first_name`?

I have set up the following model associations:

```
Product belongs to Artist
Artist belongs to Person
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Containable is definitely the way to go for filtering related records. Make sure to add $actsAs = array('Containable') into your model or app_model.

Then you can do things like:

```
$this->Product->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Artist' => array(
            'Person' => array(
                'id',
                'first_name'
            )
        )
    )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already set the relationships in these models, you just need to set it `recursive`:

```
$this->Product->recursive = 2;
print_r($this->Product->find('all'));
```

Comment: What is the actual syntax to just echo the first name?

Comment: See `print_r` to see the path. If you use `$products = $this->Product->find('all')` I guess it gonna be in `$products[0]['Artist']['People']['first_name']`.

Comment: Works using `$products[0]['Artist']['Person']['first_name']`, but using this method pulls a lot of unnecessary data, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can use `fields` to choose which fields should be retrieved. See more here http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/08/06/fields-conditions-and-associated-models-in-cakephp-12/

Comment: Think the [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) behavior may be the way to go?

Comment: Not sure I have set up the associations correctly, here is another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052833/linking-models-together) I have posted.